# Multiply Only Numeric Values in Python String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am interested in multiplying all the numbers in a Python string by a variable (y) as in the following example where y = 10.

```
Initial Input: 
"I have 15, 7, and 350 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot."
```

```
Desired Output: 
"I have 150, 70, and 3500 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot."
```

I tried the following Python code, but am not getting the desired output. How can I create the desired output in Python code?

```
string_init = "I have 15, 7, and 350 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot."

string_split = string.split()
y = 10 
multiply_string = string * (y)
print(multiply_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex here.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s =  "I have 15, 7, and 350 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot."
y = 10
print(re.sub(r"(\d+)", lambda x: str(int(x.group())*y), s))
#or 
# print(re.sub(r"(\d+)", lambda x: f"{int(x.group())*y}", s))
```

**Output:**

```
I have 150, 70, and 3500 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot.
```

Comment: I like this answer because it could be adapted pretty easily to handle decimals as well.

Comment: What exactly does the above regex statement mean and how does it work?  Does it account for different types of punctuation, non-numerics, etc.?

Comment: `(\d+)` finds ints in the string. And then it is multiplied by the required number

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
print(re.sub("(\d+)", "\g<1>0", string_init))
```

this should print:

```
I have 150, 70, and 3500 cars, boats and bikes, respectively, in my parking lot.
```

Comment: What exactly does the above regex statement mean and how does it work?  Does it account for different types of punctuation, non-numerics, etc.?